# vaadin - cannot open java files (eclipse)

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, vaadin, vaadin8

We installed the `Vaadin designer 2` but we cannot open our `java` files where the UI is located.

**Error:**

```
Vaadin Designer only supports HTML files.
```

If I would like to open html file then I got this error message:

```
org.eclipse.ui.internal.ErrorEditorPart cannot be cast to com.vaadin.designer2.eclipse.editors.VaadinEditor
```

Comment: Is this an app which was previously developed with the designer or are you trying to use the designer starting from now on? What kind of HTML did you try to open?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the answer:

Vaadin Designer 2 can open HTML files but only those that follow Vaadin Framework's declarative format. Java files can't be opened in Designer.

You can create a Designer compatible HTML file by creating a new "Vaadin 8 Design" file from Eclipse's new File menu. Please follow the steps in the documentation: https://vaadin.com/docs/v8/designer/designer-getting-started.html